# Get timestamp and convert it to string

Tags: java

I'm using this to get current timestamp in seconds and add it to a string `Double.toString((System.currentTimeMillis()/1000))`
However instead of decimal notation I get "1.23213E9". How do I switch to the decimal notation ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shortest is

```
String secs = "" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
```

If you want to retain milli-seconds you can use

```
String secs = String.format("%.3f",  System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000.0);
```

produces a String like

```
1342604140.503
```

Comment: If you need high accuracy, convert to seconds as `(double)System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000` and combine the NumberFormat example posted by @Dario

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(((System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this code has any advantage over Peter Lawrey's post, apart from being more readable.

Comment: @rineez: This is what we call reusing. Why redoing something already done?

Comment: @Mohayemin I do agree with the code reuse point there. But please note the possible loss of precision in this method. For those who need only a rounded value this method could be perfect.

Comment: @rineez Most probably you want to use seconds when you represent something in that time-range and the decimals become "unimportant". Just as you would not say the lenght of sweden is 1572.232km, you would say 1572km or 1572232m

Answer (score 7):

```
String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
```

that should do the trick? No need to convert it to a double

Answer (score 1):

If you need to deal with a Double you could do something like this:

```
double myNum = 1.23213E9;
String myString = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(myNum);
System.out.print(myString);
```